# How to open emoji section from keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

I have been searching for a package that provides me with emojis to add in my flutter chat app. I have tried the emoji picker package but it had so many bugs; for instance, if I pass the text editting controller of my `TextField` to it and then tried to add some emojis, the cursor of the `TextField` is not there as it is not currently focused on that `TextField` and when I set the `maxLines` to a certain number, after the maxLines value is reached, it will not automatically go down if another emoji is pressed, the user must scroll to see the last emoji. I also searched for custom keyboards but didn't have any luck getting what I wanted. so for now I just want to open the emoji section in the system's keyboard, how can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried emoji_selector? It seems to fit your needs